# Getting boolean value as false for Approval.islocked(id)

Tags: apex, trigger, approval-process

I am using below in my trigger.I can see lock on the record and when i try to edit it then it says locked.I am getting boolean value as false for Approval.islocked.Any suggesstion for locking record using approval process. I have kept record lock for initial submission .Other things as unlock on final.

```
(Approval.isLocked(trigger.new[index].id)
```

Trigger:

```
trigger protocol_visit_handler on Patient_Package__c (after insert, after update) {
    List<Event> events = new List<Event>([Select id,subject,Description,Event_Status__c  from Event where patient_package__c in: trigger.newMap.Keyset() and patient_package__r.Status__c ='Inactive' limit 50000]);
    map<Id,Patient_Package__c> lockPackage = new map<Id, Patient_Package__c>();
    integer index=0;
    if(Trigger.isInsert){
        System.debug('inside insert :::::');
        System.debug('value of condition 1 inside insert :::::'+(trigger.new[index].Master_Package__c != PMMConstants.patientPackVisit));
        System.debug('value of condition 2 inside insert :::::'+Approval.isLocked(trigger.new[index].id));

        if(trigger.new[index].Master_Package__c != PMMConstants.patientPackVisit && !Approval.isLocked(trigger.new[index].id)){
            System.debug('inside trigger insert condn befor try :::::');
            lockPackage.put(trigger.new[index].id,new Patient_Package__c( id=trigger.new[index].id,ECC_Sync_Status__c=label.PMM_ECC_STATUS_Processing));
            try{
                ECC_protocol_Sub_Callout.ecc_protocol_subscription(string.ValueOf(trigger.new[index].id));
                }catch(exception e){
                PMM_Exception_DAO.insertExceptionRecord(e,'ECC_Onboarding_Callout','ecccallout');
                system.debug(e.getmessage());
            }
            if(lockPackage!=null && !lockPackage.isEmpty()){
                update lockPackage.values();
            }
            System.debug('value of lockpage inside insert :::::'+lockPackage);
        }
    }
    if(Trigger.isUpdate){
        for(Patient_Package__c patPack: trigger.new){
            if(patPack.ECC_Sync_Status__c == 'Success'
            && patPack.ECC_Sync_Status__c != trigger.oldmap.get(patPack.id).ECC_Sync_Status__c ){
                PMM_EventCreate.createEvent(patPack);
            }
        }
        System.debug('inside update :::::');
        System.debug('value of condition 1 inside update :::::'+trigger.new[index].Approval_Status__c);
        if(trigger.new[index].Approval_Status__c=='Approved'){
            lockPackage.put(trigger.new[index].id,new Patient_Package__c( id=trigger.new[index].id,ECC_Sync_Status__c=label.PMM_ECC_STATUS_Processing));
            try{
                System.debug('inside try update :::::');
                ECC_protocol_Sub_Callout.ecc_protocol_subscription(string.ValueOf(trigger.new[index].id));
                lockPackage.put(trigger.new[index].id,new Patient_Package__c( id=trigger.new[index].id,Approval_Status__c=''));
                }catch(exception e){
                PMM_Exception_DAO.insertExceptionRecord(e,'ECC_Onboarding_Callout','ecccallout');
                system.debug(e.getmessage());
            }
        }
        if(lockPackage!=null && !lockPackage.isEmpty()){
            update lockPackage.values();
        }
        System.debug('value of lockpage inside update :::::'+lockPackage);
        if(!System.isFuture()){
            for(Event e : events){
                e.Event_Status__c = 'Cancelled';
                e.Description = 'Patient Package Deactivated';
            }
            if(events!= null && events.size()>0){
                update events;
            }
        }
        for (Patient_Package__c pack: Trigger.new){
            Patient_Package__c oldPack = Trigger.oldMap.get(pack.ID);
            if (pack.Status__c != oldPack.Status__c && pack.Status__c == 'Inactive') {
            lockPackage.put(trigger.new[index].id,new Patient_Package__c( id=trigger.new[index].id,ECC_Sync_Status__c=label.PMM_ECC_STATUS_Processing));
                try{
                    ECC_protocol_Sub_Callout.ecc_protocol_unsubscription(pack.id);
                    }catch(exception e){
                    PMM_Exception_DAO.insertExceptionRecord(e,'ECC_Onboarding_Callout','ecccallout');
                    system.debug(e.getmessage());
                }
            }
            if (pack.ECC_Sync_Status__c != oldPack.ECC_Sync_Status__c && pack.ECC_Sync_Status__c == 'Success') {
                //ECC_Onboarding_Callout.ecc_patient_activation(pack.Account__c);
            }
        }
        if(lockPackage!=null && !lockPackage.isEmpty()){
            update lockPackage.values();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems, (!) symbol making it as False.

Comment: "Approval.isLocked(trigger.new[index].id" is giving me as false.

Comment: What if you check the same record Id via `Execute Anonymous`? Same result?

Comment: @Adrian
String id='a0gR0000002ffJS';
System.debug('Value of :::: '+(Approval.isLocked(id)));
Yes in anonymous it is giving correct result. Why is it so ? Inside trigger it is not giving correct result

Comment: I think you should give us a more complete sample of your code. Is this `before update`, `after update`, or some other event? I think you should show the whole trigger.

Comment: @adrian-I have added whole trigger.

Comment: How would a record be locked `after insert`? Are you submitting it to approval in a `before insert` trigger or something?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46857/discussion-between-jack-vardy-and-adrian-larson).

Comment: @adrian-I have moved it to discussion